# Find_by with specific row in SQL table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`User` + `Authentications`.

A user connects Twitter and Facebook. If a user connects his account it gets stored in a `authorizations table`

A few rows of this table are `provider` and `link` (they respective profile links).

I'm trying to pull the link from a specific provider.

```
<% @user.authorizations.where(provider: 'Twitter') do |tauth| %>
  <%= link_to tauth.link, :target => '_blank' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but nothing appears, what am i missing?

The Provider Table:

`provider:` Twitter, Facebook

`link:` http://1.com, http://2.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `.each`. It should be

```
@user.authorizations.where(provider: 'Twitter').each do |tauth|
```

If it you're looking for a single record you can use `find_by`

```
tauth = @user.authorizations.find_by(provider: 'Twitter')
```

Comment: Jesus... i think i need to go sleep.. Thanks a lot Kyle :)